# Use if conditions inside a loop in Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a pipeline template which executes a different stage based on a parameter value:

```
parameters:
- name: environments
  type: object
  default: {}

stages:
  - template: templates/stage-download-packages.yml
    parameters:
      dsArtifactFeedName: "${{ parameters.dsArtifactFeedName }}"
      azureProjectName: "${{ parameters.azdoProjectName }}"

  - ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
      ${{ if eq(environment.values.isForValidation, 'false') }}:
      - template: templates/stage-deploy-to-env.yml
        parameters:
          ansibleArtifactName: "${{ environment.value.ansibleArtifactName }}"
          ansibleArtifactFeedName: "${{ environment.value.ansibleArtifactFeedName }}"
          ansibleArtifactVersion: "${{ environment.value.ansibleArtifactVersion }}"
          ansibleHostsInventoryFile: "${{ environment.value.ansibleHostsInventoryFile }}"
          ansiblePlaybookFile: "${{ environment.value.ansiblePlaybookFile }}"
          buildNumber: "${{ environment.value.buildNumber }}"
          env: "${{ environment.key }}"
          envLong: "${{ environment.value.displayName }}"
          hostFromInventory: "${{ environment.value.ansibleHostFromInventory }}"
          keyVaultConnection: "${{ environment.value.keyVaultConnection }}"
          keyVaultName: "${{ environment.value.keyVaultName }}"
          updateAzVaults: true
      ${{ if eq(environment.values.isForValidation, 'true') }}:
      - stage: "${{ environment.key }}"
        displayName: "${{ environment.value.displayName }}"
        jobs:
          - deployment: 
            environment: "${{ environment.key }}"
```

In this current situation the if statement which checks the `isForValidation` value throws an exception:

```
Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How can we use if conditions against the current item of a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was missing some indentation, this is the final code that works:

```
  - ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
      - ${{ if ne(parameters.environments[environment.key].isForValidation, 'true') }}:
        - template: templates/stage-deploy-to-env.yml
          parameters:
            ansibleArtifactName: "${{ environment.value.ansibleArtifactName }}"
            ansibleArtifactFeedName: "${{ environment.value.ansibleArtifactFeedName }}"
            ansibleArtifactVersion: "${{ environment.value.ansibleArtifactVersion }}"
            ansibleHostsInventoryFile: "${{ environment.value.ansibleHostsInventoryFile }}"
            ansiblePlaybookFile: "${{ environment.value.ansiblePlaybookFile }}"
            buildNumber: "${{ environment.value.buildNumber }}"
            env: "${{ environment.key }}"
            envLong: "${{ environment.value.displayName }}"
            hostFromInventory: "${{ environment.value.ansibleHostFromInventory }}"
            keyVaultConnection: "${{ environment.value.keyVaultConnection }}"
            keyVaultName: "${{ environment.value.keyVaultName }}"
            updateAzVaults: true
      - ${{ if eq(parameters.environments[environment.key].isForValidation, 'true') }}:
        - stage: "${{ environment.value.stageName }}"
          displayName: "${{ environment.value.displayName }}"
          jobs:
            - deployment: 
              environment: "${{ environment.key }}"
```